# ipython, find specific directories

Tags: python, ipython

I do some (beginners) programming in ipython 5.1.0.

There are about 100 directories with names like
`Mix_XFUEL_0.5_XOXID_0.6_PHI_0.2`, only the numbers are changing.

I use `fnmatch` to read the names into the programm.
Now I need all directories, in which the first two numbers (behind `XFUEL` and `XOXID`) are identically, like:

```
Mix_XFUEL_0.5_XOXID_0.5_PHI_0.2
Mix_XFUEL_0.5_XOXID_0.5_PHI_0.4
Mix_XFUEL_0.5_XOXID_0.5_PHI_0.6
```

but also

```
Mix_XFUEL_0.6_XOXID_0.6_PHI_0.2
Mix_XFUEL_0.6_XOXID_0.6_PHI_0.4
Mix_XFUEL_0.6_XOXID_0.6_PHI_0.6
```

I tried:

```
i = '0.5'  
fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'Mix_XFUEL_'i'_XOXID_'i'_PHI_*'):
```

but it won't work.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use regex, 2nd capture group `(\1)` asserted that it need to match the 1st capture group `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`

`(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` match any decimal number or number with decimal points

```
import re
re.match(r'Mix_XFUEL_(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)_XOXID_(\1)_PHI', infile)
```

this will match

- "Mix_XFUEL_0.5_XOXID_0.5_PHI_0.2"
- "Mix_XFUEL_0.6_XOXID_0.6_PHI_0.2"
- "Mix_XFUEL_5_XOXID_5_PHI_0.2"

but not

- "Mix_XFUEL_0.5_XOXID_0.6_PHI_0.2"

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, re
from collections import defaultdict

results = defaultdict(list)
for file in os.listdir('/path/to/your/directory'):
    m = re.match(r'Mix_XFUEL_(.*?)_XOXID_(.*?)_PHI_.*', file)
    if m:
        numbers = m.group(1,2)
        results[numbers].append(file)

for r in results:
    print(results[r])
```

Comment: Thanks. The code "around" the regex  helps me a lot, too. Combined with regex from the other answer, this fits quite properly.